# Setting processing.guarentee to exactly_once creates deserialization error at python consumer kafka

Tags: python, apache-kafka, confluent-kafka-python

I have java Kafka stream processing application and python application. Java application produces data and python consumer consumes it. When the `processing.guarantee` is set to `exactly_once`, then the python consumer is not able to deserialize the data. Deserialization fails.

I tried a java consumer and the java consumer is successfully reading the data. Then I turned back the `processing.guarantee` to `atleast_once` in java application. Now the python application is able to read without any issue.

I checked the payload from a console consumer and in both cases of `exactly_once` and `atleast_once` the payload looks same. Even the binary payload read at python consumer before deserializtion in both cases looks same. What could be the problem in this scenario.

Note: In my case the kafka doesn't have atleast 3 brokers which is suggested in the documentation for `exactly_once` to work. Its only one in my setup.

Can anyone throw some light into why java consumer was working but not python consumer.

Update: Looking at the python logs much deeper looks like two records are being tried to process in python consumer

1. Original record - which is processed perfectly fine.
2. An empty record - log shows as follows  key = `b'\x00\x00\x00\x01'` and value = `b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'`. But now Iam wondering how this additional record is send when `exactly_once` is set.

Below is the python code used.

```
params = {
     "bootstrap_servers": "localhost:29092",
     "auto_offset_reset": "latest",
     "group_id": "test",
}

def set_consumer(self):
    try:
        consumer = KafkaConsumer(*self.topics, **self.consumer_params)
        return consumer
    Exception e:
       print(e)

for msg in self.consumer:
    try:
        event = self.decode_msg(msg)
        self.logger.info("Json result : %s", str(event))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> wondering how this additional record is send when exactly_once is set

It is a transaction marker. The Java consumer is able to detect these and filter them out, but in Python, your deserializer will need to handle them separately. There is a [Github issue thread](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/issues/357) that suggests the consumer should already be able to filter the transaction records; maybe check the librdkafka docs if you are missing any configurations for this.

I see there is an [EOS example in the confluent-kafka-python repo](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/blob/master/examples/eos-transactions.py), but it doesn't consume after the producer sends the transaction records.

Comment: Can you also add the importance of the transaction marker record or some links to it

Comment: It enables exactly once delivery as consumers know where producer transaction boundaries occur. Maybe refer to this? https://developer.confluent.io/learn-kafka/architecture/transactions/